# How to select and print IP address from a set of strings?

Tags: command-line, scripts, sed

I have a sentence whic contains an IP address. For example,

```
This sentence contains an ip number 1.2.3.4 and port number 50, i want to print the IP address only.
```

From the above sentence, I want to print the IP address only. How can I do this? I heard that it is possible to do this with `sed`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible, but not elegant:

```
echo 'This sentence contains an ip number 1.2.3.4 and port number 50, i want to print the IP address only.' \
| sed 's/.*\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\).*/\1/'
```

`[0-9]` matches any digit, `\{1,3\}` means it can be repeated 1 to 3 times. `\.` matches a dot. The whole IP is captured by the `\(...\)` parentheses, what comes before and after is matched by `.*`, i.e. anything repeated zero or more times. The whole matching string (i.e. the whole line) is then replaced by the contents of the first matching group.

You can make it more readable by introducing a variable:

```
n='[0-9]\{1,3\}'
... | sed "s/.*\($n\.$n\.$n\.$n\).*/\1/"
```

It prints the whole string if the IP is not found. It also doesn't check for invalid IPs like 256.512.999.666.

Comment: Could you please explain me how this works. It might help me more to learn sed.

Comment: @AnanduMDas: Updated.

Comment: One more help can you do? If I have a new line after this line, then that line is also getting printed. Can I force sed to check for the first line only?

Comment: For multiline processing, I'd turn to Perl.

Answer (score 6):

This is a `grep` solution:

```
echo "$sentence" | grep -oE '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
```

- `-o` print only the matching part
- `-E` switches to extended regex
- the pattern matches every digit (`[0-9]`) one or more times (`+`) then a dot (`\.`) and again digits...

Here another solution with `perl`:

```
echo "$sentence" | perl -l -ne '/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ && print $&'
```

- `-l` specified the line terminator (newline)
- `-n` loops trough the input given by `echo` (could be multiple lines)
- `-e` code follows
- the regex inside the perl code is very much the same as in the `grep` solution above

Comment: @chaos wouldn't grep match any character for the `.`, given that you included the `-E` option?

Comment: @skeggse Ur right, I changed it, thanks for your note

Comment: @AvinashRaj It a question of perfection. `[0-9]{1,3}` would match `987.567.432.999` too and that's not a valid ip address.

Comment: @chaos yeah, but by that logic your regex matches `298724387956458376345.1.1.1`, which is definitely not a valid ip address.

Comment: @skeggse "definitely not valid" and "not valid" is the same. Things can't be *more* invalid than other things. =)

Comment: @chaos very true :)

Comment: @skeggse see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_1zoX5Ax9U

Comment: Sure, things can be more invalid than other things. A lot of product version numbers (at least in the Windows world) look like `38.0.2125.111`, and there's value in having a regex that's smart enough not to confuse that with an IP address.

Answer (score 2):

Use this command of `grep`:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9.]+ ' file
```

Or even better:

```
grep -oP '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' file
```

or

```
grep -Eo "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" file
```

Answer (score 1):

I use grep:

```
echo 'This sentence contains an ip number 1.2.3.4 and port number 50, i want to print the IP address only.' | grep -oE '((1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}((1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))'
```

This will print only valid ip adresses, unlike the other answers

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this in python 3 interpreter. It not only grabs the text which are in this `111.111.111.111` format but also it checks for valid or not.

```
>>> import re
>>> import ipaddress
>>> text = "This sentence contains an ip number 1.2.3.4 and 111.111.111.111 451.976.897.786 port number 50, i want to print the IP address only."
>>> foo = re.findall(r'(?<!\S)(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(?!\S)', text)
>>> foo
['1.2.3.4', '111.111.111.111', '451.976.897.786']
>>> for i in foo:
...     try:
...         ipaddress.ip_address(i)
...     except:
...         pass
... 
IPv4Address('1.2.3.4')
IPv4Address('111.111.111.111')
```

To get the python 3 interpreter, type `python3` command on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Extension to choroba's answer:

If you don't want new line to be printed and you only want to print IP's:

```
$ echo -e 'This sentence contains an ip number 1.2.3.4 and port number 50, \ni want to print the IP address only.\n One more IP is 1.24.53.3.' \
| sed -n 's/.*\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\).*/\1/1p'
```

Output:

```
1.2.3.4
1.24.53.3
```

Explanation:

```
-n flag is for quiet / silent.
 p print the replaced text
```

Answer (score 0):

AWK combined with RegExp is very appropriate for processing parts of lines.

Basic idea of the one-liner bellow is to for-loop through a line, and check for presence of four digits and dots, repeated at maximum 4 times; at the same time we can check for a digit repeated 2 to 4 times for port number

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i~/[[:digit:]\.]{4}/) printf $i; if ( $i~/[[:digit:]]{2,4}/) printf ":"$i  }}'
```

Sample run

```
$ echo "This sentence contains an ip number 1.2.3.4 and port number 50, i want to print the IP address only." |  awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i~/[[:digit:]\.]{4}/) printf $i; if ( $i~/[[:digit:]]{2,4}/) printf ":"$i  }}'

1.2.3.4:50,
```

Your sentence contains 50 and, together without separation, hence printed together, but with `gsub(/[[:punct:]]/,"")` that can be removed if desired.